# counting the number of function calls in a C program

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

A C source program is given. Determine, for each defined function in
the source, the number of calls, and the line where the call occurs.

The best thing I could come up with is `grep -c 'function (' code.c`
However this only works if I know the function name, and it will only provide the number of calls (considering there is no prototype in that file). Not sure with what else to start so any advice would be well met.

Comment: You can't do this reliably with standard shell tools. You need a C parser like cscope (http://cscope.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ctags` can reliably give you a list of function names, e.g.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    printf ("Hello World!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

$ ctags -x --c-types=f test.c
foo              function      3 test.c           void foo(void)
main             function      8 test.c           int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Does this help you to get started?

Answer (score 2):

Download cscope (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope) from http://cscope.sourceforge.net/ and then do something like this (check the options/syntax):

1) Build the database (I'll name it db.csc) from your source files:

```
cscope -b -u -f db.csc *.c *.h ....
```

2) Search the database for all function calls:

```
cscope -d -f db.csc -L -3 '.*'
```

and it will give you a list of every function + which function it calls + the line number that call occurs on. You may need to read the man page and play with the options a bit as it's been years since I last did this.

Answer (score -2):

You better do that in a few steps.

First, get all the functions names off the file and save it in a temporary file, using grep and awk. Something like:

```
$ grep ^function code.c | awk '{print $2 }' > /tmp/toto
```

Next, for every entry in the temp file, search all the occurences of the name of the function in the code.c file and get the line number of each call. Something like:

```
cat /tmp/toto | while read line; do
grep -n $line code.c
echo total: `grep $line code.c | wc -l` times
done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do this for every existing function in the code.c file, and that I'm not supposed to know the function names.

Comment: That's the point of the first bit, extracting the function names from the code.c and keeping them in a temporary file.

Comment: @axesdenied - you never need to use grep AND awk. The first line above can be written as just `awk '/^function/{print $2}' code.c > /tmp/toto`. The subsequent loop unnecessarily uses cat (UUOC) and will fail at various points for file names that contain white space, newlines, backslashes, shell globbing characters (e.g. ? or *) , etc., etc. and will produce false matches due to not anchoring of the regexp grep is using.

Comment: Yeah that's right, of course is not perfect. I wasn't developing a solution for a production environment here, but giving some guidelines to solve a problem. That's why I say "something like", not "below the definitive solution".